# Layers list is missing due to fliter?

Tags: hidden-file

I accidentally applied a filter somehow to my layers. I can't figure out how to undo it? I was working on a birthday present for my friend.

[image: I accidentally applied a filter somehow to my layers. I can't figure out how to undo it? I was working on a birthday present for my friend.]

Answer (score 0):

Layer filters have an on/off toggle when you click each filter icon.
For normal view, disable all filters.

Disable the shape layer filter by clicking

[image]